# 0% Impression CTR in Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

Number of impressions in my app is very very good but as the Impression CTR is 0%, i believe my earnings are very much less.
Is there any way using which i can improve my Impression CTR ??

Further, if Impression CTR is not the problem, then is there any other reason for such low earnings?

I have attached a screenshot for my App Statistics of 7 Days. [image]

Please Help me out. 
Thank You In Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

So your CTR is a bit under 0.2%. That is very low.

One of the reasons it could be low is if you are asking for ads very frequently. 
What is your refresh rate?

I find it best to use something around 60 seconds.

Comment: My refresh rate for the same is 60 seconds.
should change it to "NO REFRESH" ??

Comment: No. You want tome refresh. 60 seconds should be fine. Are your users staying in your app long enough to see the ads?

Comment: NO, 
my users stays in app just for couple of seconds. i.e. ads are on login page.

Comment: That's the reason for your low CTR then. You are making ad requests,most of which the user never gets a chance to click on. You might need to rethink your monetization strategy, or get them to stick around your app a little while.

Comment: any suggestions for that ?

Comment: That depends entirely upon what your app is, which is a whole different question.